# Applying 600VDC to a phototriac? What will happen?

Tags: triac

I am using Vishay's VO2223. https://www.vishay.com/docs/81166/vo2223.pdf

Our tester applied 600VDC to this phototriac device. It exploded. Load current is below the max (0.9A).

Why that happened?

Comment: Applied 600v where - between which pins, under what conditions?

Comment: 1) Which two pins had 600V between them, 2) what voltages were applied to the other pins at the time?. You can add these details to your question using the "edit" button on the right level with your name.

Comment: A triac is a latching switch that relies on AC to unlatch for each alternating half cycle. Thus your Triac cannot be used for DC.

Comment: "Load current is below the max (0.9A)." - what was the _actual_ load current, and how was it achieved?

Answer (score 3):

The **ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM** voltage rating for this device is 600V peak **AC** (not DC), Sine wave, 50 Hz to 60 Hz, gate open.

Your reference to load current below 0.9A implies that the tester attempted to *operate* the device at 600VDC. The datasheet says this:-

> Stresses in excess of the absolute maximum ratings can cause
>   permanent damage to the device. **Functional operation of the device is
>   not implied** at these or any other conditions in excess of those given
>   in the operational sections of this document. Exposure to absolute
>   maximum ratings for extended periods of the time can adversely affect
>   reliability.

Without knowing exactly how the tester applied the 600VDC we can only speculate about what caused the breakdown. That it 'exploded' suggests rapid overheating of the die, which implies that current was higher than 0.9A and/or the device was only partially turned on (perhaps due to excessive Dv/Dt or reaching breakdown voltage). With DC voltage applied, once turned on it would not have been able to turn off, which could eventually cause it to overheat even if load current was 'below' 0.9A.

Answer (score 0):

The device **is** guaranteed to block 600VDC (Vdrm).

**However**, the critical dv/dt is stated to be 210V/us at 25°C. If the test switched the 600VDC on faster than several microseconds and/or the temperature exceeded 25°C, the thyristor would likely trigger causing it to turn on, and current would be limited only by the internal junctions and whatever you have in series externally.

900mA is way too high for that part- it will likely burn up and possibly fail catastrophically eventually. That's the absolute maximum RMS current at 25°C. Probably 300mA is a more reasonable maximum for a serious design. It will still get quite warm at 0.3A.

[image]

The triac will not turn off until the current drops below the holding current, and the minimum is not specified.